# ajax javascript ASP date validator not working correctly for 2020 dates

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, frontend

Hi I have a website that is currently not allowing any dates from this year to be selected or manually typed. It shows an error that the date is not valid. I checked the code to try to figure out whats going on and I believe I have narrowed it down to an ajax asp control that someone previously had a set format but I do not understand what the characters mean. Format is MM/dd/yyyy  ,Any help appreciated.

```html
<value>^((0?[13578]|10|12)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[01]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1}))|(0?[2469]|11)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[0]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1})))$</value>
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Why not try to parse the date to see if its valid using JavaScript's `Date` object or C#'s `DateTime`?  Regex seems like the very wrong tool for this job.  Regex can check if it fits the `MM/dd/yyyy` format, but not whether it is a *valid* date.

Comment: Unfortunately that is what I have to work with as I am limited in dev skills and I just want this to work as is. Will take a look at your suggestions though .Thank you